# Browse and Upload a file in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm writing tests for Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM using Selenium in C#. I need to write a test for browsing and uploading a file, but I want it to be universal so that anyone can run the code, not just with my local file path. How can I achieve that?

This is my code in ContactPage.cs and also UploadDocumentSteps.cs

```
public ContactsPage UploadDocumentContact(string iRType)
{
    WaitUntilElementIsVisible(uploadDocuments);
    Click(uploadDocuments);
    Wait(10);
    WaitUntilElementIsVisible(dontAllow_btn);
    Click(dontAllow_btn);
    WaitUntilElementIsVisible(browse_btn);
    Click(browse_btn);

    return this;
}

[When(@"Upload document from ""([^""]*)""")]
public void WhenCreateIllustrationRequestFrom(string IRType)
{
    switch (IRType.ToUpper())
    {
        case Data.Accounts:
            accountsPage = new AccountsPage(driver).OpenIRAccount();
            break;
        case Data.Investor:
            contactsPage = new ContactsPage(driver).OpenInvestorContact();
            break;
        case Data.Locations:
            locationsPage = new LocationsPage(driver).OpenExistingLocation();
            break;
        case Data.Cases:
            casesPage = new CasesPage(driver).SearchForCase();
            break;
            throw new Exception($"{IRType} type is not found...");
    }

    accountsPage = new AccountsPage(driver).UploadDocumentAccount(IRType);
    contactsPage = new ContactsPage(driver).UploadDocumentContact(IRType);
    locationsPage = new LocationsPage(driver).UploadDocumentLocation(IRType);
    casesPage = new CasesPage(driver).UploadDocumentCase(IRType);
}
```

And here is feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Verify Upload Document
    Given User navigates to CRM application with valid credentials
    When User navigates to "<page>" page
    And Upload document from "<IRType>"
    Then Document should be Uploaded successfully
 
    Examples: 
    | page          | IRType        |
    | Accounts      | Accounts      |
    | Contacts      | Investor      |
    | Locations     | Locations     |
    | Cases         | Cases         |
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. You've provided some code but didn't indicate where the problem is. You've also provided only part of the code... you're using several custom methods like `WaitUntilElementIsVisible()` and `Click()` but didn't include the code for those methods. You haven't provided any of the HTML of the page, etc. Please edit your question and clarify exactly what you need from us, what isn't working, and the current and expected behavior.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I have a couple suggestions. `Click()` should handle wait for clickable inside it and not rely on calling `WaitUntilElementIsVisible()` before it. 2. Make `IRType` an enum. Without the rest of the code, I can't tell but it looks like `Data` is an enum? If so, pass `Data` into `WhenCreateIllustrationRequestFrom()` as a parameter, e.g. `public void WhenCreateIllustrationRequestFrom(enum Data)` then you can get rid of the `.ToUpper()` call.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are using `UploadDocumentAccount`

Comment: to upload a file you'd use sendKeys() on the <input type="file"> element.   The keys you send would be a string that is an absolute path to the file.  (yes, it needs to be absolute, so you would need to extract this file at run-time, or scan for an existing file to be sure of its location and existence)